# Solving a system of (projectile motion) second order differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, mathematical-physics, projectile-motion

I have a system of two second order differential equations, and some initial conditions. I know how to solve it using MATLAB but my problem is with the 4 initial conditions,  two of them have an unknown value that is the initial velocity. And can I solve them with only two initial conditions?. How do I write them so as to solve these equations?

[The photo of the equations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tDCVB.png)

I want to find the value of initial velocity. Values for all constants are given, the value for the angle and mass too.
I'll appreciate any input. Thanks

Comment: To sum up the equations: You're trying to numerically solve the equations of motion for an object undergoing projectile motion subject to gravity and aerodynamic drag (force $\vec{F}_d = -\beta v\vec{v}$). The initial condition is that the object is launched from the origin, moving at angle $\theta_0$ with initial speed $v_0$.

Comment: that is correct